# Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created a web API and it was working fine earlier. I am getting the below error suddenly when I am trying to browse through the API.

`Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

`Config Source:`
   `30:      <customHeaders>`

`31:        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>`

`32:        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>`

I have below code in the web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
 </customHeaders>
```

Can anyone suggest me what could be the issue here as it was working fine before.

Comment: Looks like somewhere else you also add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Answer (score 8):

If this has been released or published, check the other web.configs which perform transforms.

It sounds like there is probably a transform in your web.release.config which is adding a duplicate entry. If there is, it's probably something like this:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
```

Alternatively, if the API is living in a sub-application in IIS, an equivalent entry may be in the main site's web.config. In which case, you need to put something like this in your web.config above the add line:

```
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error message indicates , there are duplicate collection entry. You can try add the following section just above the actual Add:

```
<remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"/>
```

Or simply, you can *comment* the line:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```

The website will inherits the settings form parent level . This should be the reason of this issue. You can check if there is a web.config file in the parent web content folder(e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\arif\ or C:\inetpub\wwwroot ) and an duplicate collection entry in it.